# Add child data attribute name and value to parent for each

Tags: jquery, parent-child, attr

I have looped divs that contain a child element with a data attribute named `data-rating`. What I need to do is grab the child's attribute and value and add to the parent div for each.

**Here is the code:**

```
<div class="tile">                                      
    <div class="title-band">
        <h3>Test Agency</h3>
        <ul data-rating="3.0" class="rating" data-id="13">
            <li class="whole"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span></li>
        </ul>                   
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tile">                                      
    <div class="title-band">
        <h3>Another Agency</h3>
        <ul data-rating="2.0" class="rating" data-id="14">
            <li class="whole"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span></li>
        </ul>                   
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I'd like to accomplish:

```
<div class="tile" data-rating="3.0">                                        
    <div class="title-band">
        <h3>Test Agency</h3>
        <ul data-rating="3.0" class="rating" data-id="13">
            <li class="whole"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span></li>
        </ul>                   
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tile" data-rating="2.0">                                        
    <div class="title-band">
        <h3>Test Agency</h3>
        <ul data-rating="2.0" class="rating" data-id="14">
            <li class="whole"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span></li>
        </ul>                   
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the parent div using its class `title-band` then use .attr() to set the attribute value like

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.title-band').attr('data-rating', function () {
        return $(this).find('ul').data('rating')
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J7Jkb/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul[data-rating]').each(function(i,a) {
    $(a).parent().attr('data-rating', $(a).data('rating'));
});
```

Comment: ugh... you beat me to it.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`div` with a child element that has `data-rating` attribute:

```
$('div > [data-rating]').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().attr('data-rating', $(this).data('rating'));
});
```

if the child element is not the first level, remove the `>`.